# MariaDB with groupBy and Where statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am new to SQL. I have 2 tables

DateNow: August 23, 2021

**Transaction**

```
ID         Code   
10001      ABC111
10002      DD0988
10003      GGT555
```

**Booking**

```
ID       TransactionID   TravelDate   Amount
50001      10001         10-10-2021    500.00
50002      10001         08-24-2021    200.00
50003      10001         08-26-2021    100.00
50004      10002         12-22-2021    200.00
50004      10002         11-22-2021    200.00
50005      10003         08-24-2021    100.00
```

I have a select statement:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Code, b.ID, b.TravelDate , b.Amount
FROM transaction t JOIN
 Booking b
 ON b.TransactionID = t.ID
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
          FROM booking b2
          WHERE b2.TransactionID = t.ID AND
                b2.TravelDate >= curdate() - interval 5 day
         )
```

ORDER BY t.ID, b.TravelDate;

What I supposed to get is:

```
50001      10001         10-10-2021    500.00
50002      10001         08-24-2021    200.00
50003      10001         08-26-2021    100.00
50005      10003         08-24-2021    100.00
```

but it seem that I am only getting

```
50002      10001         08-24-2021    200.00
50003      10001         08-26-2021    100.00
```

is there a way to get rid of the inner select?

Comment: Your query is invalid in several ways, and should raise an error.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you help me achieve to get all bookings in one transaction that atleast one of their bookings have the minimum date less than 5 days?

This suggests `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Code, b.ID, b.TravelDate , b.Amount
FROM transaction t JOIN
     Booking b
     ON b.TransactionID = t.ID
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM booking b2
              WHERE b2.TransactionID = t.ID AND
                    b2.TravelDate >= curdate() - interval 5 day
             )
ORDER BY t.ID, b.TravelDate;
```

Note:  This interprets "minimum date less than 5 days" as "most recent booking date within the past five days (or in the future)", based on the logic in your query.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am wondering, is there another way to achieve that without using an inner select? @gordon

Comment: @AbramYu . . . Lots of ways, in fact, but this answers your question and is a good approach.